# PHP: Destroy an object from within the object?

Tags: php, object, destroy

Is there a way in PHP to destroy an object from within that same object?

Comment: No, I don't think there is. But would you need such thing?

Comment: @Christian the ability to destroy an object leis in the same place where the ability to create them - not inside the object itself.

Comment: gave a "yes-and-here-is-how" answer to an essentially similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21367011/1537018

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way to self destruct an object :

Use the `$GLOBALS` array to find your instance in it, then use `unset()`. Be aware that `unset()` does not automatically call the `__destruct()` magic method all the time...

There is such a note in this way (see the `unset()` documentation) in the PHP documentation, but it does not explain exactly when `unset()` does not call the `__destruct()` method.

And I had this specific behaviour :

I do a :

```cpp
unset($myInstance);
$myInstance = clone $otherInstance;
```

And the `__constructor` is called first, then the `__destruct()`. Or I would like the `__destruct()` to be called first because `unset()` is before clone...
I ma stuck with that now...

Nicolas.

Comment: Destructors are called on garbage collection or when the script terminates.

Comment: As hakre stated, until the $myInstance variable is out of scope and garbage collection picks it up, the destructor will not be called.

Answer (score 12):

If a method is called in the object's context then there has to be at least one reference to that object. And since php only removes unreachable objects the answer is: no.